# Is there a new way to unit test Rails projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I am following the tutorials at http://www.railstutorial.org/ and everything development wise is going well so far.  I run into a problem, however, when I get the starting to work on the unit tests.

For example, one of the tests is the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do
  describe "Home page" do
    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end
.
.
.
  end
end
```

In order to get the test to work, I have to change it to `require 'test_helper'` but then when I try to `bundle exec rake test` it gives me errors about no such `describe` method.

One test that I am able to get to run successfully is the following:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def test_connection    
    get "/about"
    assert_response :success, "missing about page"
    assert_select 'title', "About Us"
  end
end
```

I am just wondering if there was some change in the way the unit testing is parsed, because it seems that the syntax is quite different.  Is there something I need to do differently to get the "describe" method to work, or is there just a new way of accomplishing the same task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code block uses the [`rspec`](http://rspec.info/) framework, while the second one uses [`Test::Unit`](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/) framework.

Both are legitimate unit-testing frameworks, each with its own strengths, and each with its own syntax...

Both have been around for quite awhile now, so, to answer your question - no, nothing has changed...

Comment: Ah, I think that Test::Unit was the information I needed. Now I can find the rest of the syntax for that.

Comment: So then, would 'spec_helper' have worked, then the rspec syntax would be correct?

Comment: If you had `rspec` installed and you had a `spec_helper.rb`, yes, it is a correct rspec syntax